# Multiplying values in Excel 2013 (Same cell)

Tags: microsoft-excel

If for example I have a value in cell A1, lets say 2

What I want to do is multiply that cell by 0.75 but in the same cell

I don't want to have to put a formula in B1 such as =(A1*0.75), because I already have a value in B1 and I don't want to have to insert a new column.

if I highlight cell A1 and put the formula =(A1*1.333) into it the value becomes 0.00

Can what I'm asking be done? or would I need to create a macro?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah you'll  need VBA to do it. It's a circular reference, that's not how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done. Go to an empty cell and put in the value you want to multiply by. In your example this is .75 then copy and select cell a1, but now select paste special from the ribbon and then select multiply

It will change the value as desired.